# tabs.executeScript encounters ReferenceError when accessing a function defined in Content Script

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, webextension-polyfill

**Update**:
It seems the problem comes from the fact that Webpack executes each module in its own function, meaning that no modules can exist in the global scope. Is there any elegant way to solve this problem, so that I can define a function in a Webpacked content script and access it from a different content script?

**Original**:

in my primary content script I define a function

```
function foo() {
    console.log("foo")
}
```

In my `background.js`, I inject a new content script like so:

```
browser.tabs.query({currentWindow: true, active: true}).then(res => {
    browser.tabs.executeScript(res.id, {code: "foo()"})
})
```

In my tab's console, I see

```
VM181:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: foo is not defined
at <anonymous>:1:1
```

Both content scripts should be in the same execution environment, so I should be able to share functions and variables in both scripts.

I've recently added Webpack for building my Chrome extension, and I'm using [Webextension-Polyfill](https://github.com/mozilla/webextension-polyfill) to promisify the `chrome.*` API as `browser`.

In the old version of my code this worked fine, but now it's not working. I have a feeling it's because of Webextension-Polyfill but I honest' can't figure it out.

**EDIT**:

The `executeScript` code IS being run in the tab. I can `console.log` and it appears in the console. However, it doesn't seem to have access to the namespace of my existing content script.

**EDIT 2**:

I added another content script with

```
function foo() {
    console.log("foo")
}
```

And it's accessible from the injected script. So I guess it's something to do with Webpack.

Is it something to do with scoping in Webpack bundles?

Comment: _Both content scripts should be in the same execution environment._ You're wrong. Each content script is executed in its own environment isolated from others. If you want some function to be available in multiple content scripts, you have to place it in background script.

Comment: Well I just added another content script with

   ``` function foo() {
        console.log("foo")
    }```

and it was accessible from the `executeScript` injected content script. So it should be possible - **see my edit**

Comment: @hindmost likely misunderstood that the OP meant the content scripts of **one extension** in a given tab share a single common isolated world environment, which is correct. What the OP wants to do is totally correct and it works without webpack. The OP's problem here is how to configure webpack to export/expose functions from the auto-generated closure into the global context.

Comment: I see some similar questions when googling for "how to expose functions globally in webpack" and apparently you need to do it manually (or maybe there's a plugin) by assigning window.foo = foo where foo is the name of your function.